# @Html.EditorFor is Not Available inside the View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Web Express. In my ASP.NET MVC application view I cannot call or even see the @Html.EditorFor method. The intellisense never pops it up.

Any ideas?

EDITED: Same goes with @Html.BeginForm. The method never pops up!

Comment: Do you have a reference to System.Web.Mvc in your project?

Comment: If you do, then you should be able to view it in your object browser and go to System.Web.Mvc.Html EdtorExtensions and see it there.

Comment: Yes I do have a reference! I am using VS 2013 Web Express for development. Maybe it has issues.

Comment: You may be correct. Can you view System.Web.Mvc in ObjectBrowser and see if it has EditorExtensions. You should see all the EditorFor methods there.

Comment: Okay I can see it but not sure how to use it.  @System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor<StoryViewModel> does not work??

Comment: How about if you put @using System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions at the top of the view?

Comment: I tried but it does not recognize EditorExtensions. I am download VS 2013. Express versions are crap!!

Comment: I downloaded VS 2013 and still the same issues.

Comment: Do you use Resharper?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich I have not installed resharper yet! Yup! good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the namespace is not available.
In the first instance, try adding

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
```

at the top of your view to see if that helps. If it does, then there is probably a problem with your View specific `Web.config`. In the root of your `Views` folder there should be a `Web.config` file. Note that if you use Areas then there should be one of those in each `Views` folder.

Inside that `Web.config` there should be a section like the following:

```
<configuration>
...other stuff...

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication1" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

...other stuff...
</configuration>
```

Essentially that section is the equivalent of adding `using` statements inside each view.